# I opened my camera after taking 5 pictures and it rewound to 0, how many do I have left ? 36 roll

Tags: film

I think I loaded my film wrong because every time I advance the shutter it cracks a little, like if it’s tilted or too tight. I didn’t want to ruin the whole roll so I opened it up in a pitch black closet and tried to readjust it. When I closed it back up it was reset to 0 pictures and seems to be making the same sound but milder. I took a few pictures but I’m wondering how many I pictures I aveually have left before I take it out. Do the first few pictures I took count ? Thank you so much!

Comment: what is your camera model? When the issue started? Did this camera work before?

Comment: Why is the answer not 31?

Comment: Did you reload the film at the beginning of the roll? Did the camera reset only the counter, or did it "rewound" the film?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a camera with a film advance lever, then simply estimate how much you have left and when you get near the end, monitor how hard you are cranking the lever. You should be able to feel when you’re at the end.

If you feel some tension on a crank that suddenly releases, then you broke the film off the reel in the canister. Simply unload in a darkroom or take the whole camera to the lab and let them know you broke the film off. No worries.

> pitch black closet

Did you sit in the closet for 5 minutes to let your eyes adjust and then look for light? Just because you think it’s dark doesn’t mean it was. You’re probably in the clear, but if you have some fogged frames, this could be a cause.